# Why is the default parameter value of the overloaded base class value chosen, instead of the default specified in the executed derived method

Tags: c++

I've noticed a strange thing while playing with logical shift. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class C
{
public:
    virtual int shift(int n = 2) const { return n << 2; }
};
class D
    : public C
{
public:
    int shift(int n = 1) const { return n << 5; }
};
int main()
{
    const D d;
    const C *c = &d;
    cout << c->shift() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The programme returns 64, so it takes value n = 2 from the class C and the function's body from class D.

It works fine after removing const from functions but I don't understand why. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Sorry. I've corrected it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default argument values are based on the **static type** (the type known at compile time).

The choice of virtual function implementation is governed by the object's most derived type at run time, the **dynamic type**.